# Facebook Like, Share and facePiles in static html page are not loaded on hosted environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, facebook-like

I am trying to load facebook like plugin in html5 page. My code works fine in JsFiddle and w3schools executer but it is not working in my hosted environment.
My Code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Top Ten With social networking</title>
<meta name="description" content="ten" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top != self) {
        window.open(self.location.href, '_top');
    }
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- CSS3 Animation -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate-custom.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- Some Style for Demo -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global-demo.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- sample CSS Pack -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body  onLoad="$('#fb1,#fb2,#fb3,#fb4,#fb5,#fb6,#fb7,#fb8,#fb9,#fb10').slideToggle(500);">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="mainform">
  <h1> <img src="images/demo/sonhlab-80.png" alt="" /> <a href="#" target="_blank">LisTop</a> </h1>

  <!-- START -->
  <ul class="topten height-500">    
    <!-- Start Tab 1 -->
    <li>       
      <!-- Start Tab Button -->
      <label for="tab11" class="tabtile tabtile-small solid-blue-2 hovershadow-blue light-text"> <i class="icon-film icon-3x"></i> <span class="light-text">Movies</span> </label>
      <input type="radio" name="topten" id="tab11">
      <!-- End Tab Button --> 

      <!-- Start Tab Content -->
      <div class="tab-content animated tab-bounceIn solid-blue-2 light-text pos-top-100" style="width:100%" align="center">
        <p class="title">Movies</p>
        <div align="center"> 
          <!--    <button onClick="$('#fb1,#fb2,#fb3,#fb4,#fb5,#fb6,#fb7,#fb8,#fb9,#fb10').slideToggle(500);">View More...</button>-->         </div>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="96%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th align="left">Column1</th>
              <th align="left" >Column2</th>
              <th align="left" >Column3</th>
              <th align="left" >Column6</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="empty">1</span></td>
              <td>111</td>
              <td>111</td>
              <td><i class="icon-facebookSq icon-1x" onClick="$('#fb1').slideToggle(500);"></i></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="fb1">
              <td colspan="6" align="center" bgcolor="#cff4f7"> fb1
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/BoomEvent" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" align="center"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="empty">2</span></td>
              <td>222</td>
              <td>2222</td>
              <td><i class="icon-facebookSq icon-1x" onClick="$('#fb2').slideToggle(500);"></i></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="fb2">
              <td colspan="6" align="center" bgcolor="#cff4f7"> fb2
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/BoomEvent" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" align="center"></div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- End Tab Content --> 
    </li>
    <!-- End Tab 1 -->
  </ul>
  <!-- END -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The present hosted link is: http://maxoft.in/index_2.html

Expected Scenario: On clicking on the FB icon the facepiles and the fb like button should be visible in the hosted environment.
Actual Scenario: Facebook facepiles, Likes, Share buttons are not visible on loading.

Kindly help me to achieve the existing scenario. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Browser console says app id is missing – so include it in your initialization of the JS SDK, as the code generator for the like button shows.

Comment: It gets loaded in the machine where it has a good internet speed.